# How to prevent Nautilus panes from resizing automatically?

Tags: nautilus

The "Extra Pane" (F3) view in Nautilus automatically resizes in a couple situations. Is there a way to turn this off so they each stay at 50%?

The two situations are when there's one tab on one side and more than one are opened on the other, or when a directory for an external device which contains pictures is opened in one pane.

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Comment: Since Nautilus 3.6, this is no longer relevant since the "panes" feature has been removed. See [AskUbuntu.com: Is there a way to restore Nautilus' split screen (F3) feature?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285588/).