# Is there a way to join multiple Nautilus windows into one window with different tabs?

Tags: nautilus

Many times I end up with many Nautilus windows open. I would like to reduce clutter by joining them into one window with different tabs.

Is there a(n easy) way?

Comment: You could try and [restore the good old Nautilus F3 pane feature](http://askubuntu.com/questions/285588/is-there-a-way-to-restore-nautilus-split-screen-f3-feature) - looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Hj1.png).

Comment: check [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh) with `-a` option, does exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh -a`
that scritpt be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/scriptechocolor/git/ci/master/tree/ScriptEchoColor/bin.extras/secNautilusRestartAndRestoreTabs.sh).

you may need to install its latest dependencies from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scriptechocolor/files/Ubuntu%20.deb%20packages/).

will do exactly what you said, but you have to be a bit patient waiting it end running, and... that script is experimental but works very fine here.